# How can i plot the ADABoost Classifier decision boundary of each base classifiers in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-mining, adaboost

I searched in everywhere but couldn't find a way to do that. I used make_moons() data in my code and run a logistic regression model. After that i created ADABoost Classifier with 4  base classifiers and used logistic regression model for base estimator. My next task is to plot the decision boundary of **each base classifiers** The output should include 4 decision boundary. How can i plot the decision boundary of each base classifiers?

My code so far :

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier


X, y = make_moons(n_samples=100, noise=0.2)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
logisticRegr = LogisticRegression()
logisticRegr.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf= AdaBoostClassifier(logisticRegr,n_estimators=4)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fitted `AdaBoostClassifier` (`clf` here) exposes its fitted base estimators in the attribute `estimators_`, and also defines itself as an iterable ([source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0fb307bf39bbdacd6ed713c00724f8f871d60370/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py#L171)), so you can just loop over `clf` to get the base estimators.  Then you can just use their decision methods to plot.

I happen to have previously make [a notebook that did almost this](https://github.com/bmreiniger/datascience.stackexchange/blob/master/CV483796.ipynb) for a [CV.SE question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483796/improve-adaboost-that-using-weighted-logistic-regression-instead-of-decision-tre); you can probably get a good start from that.